# MS Teams - automatic addin integration

Tags: microsoft-teams, add-in, microsoft-graph-teams

I built a MS Teams Add-In. If I create a new meeting, I have to add the Add-In every time manually to this meeting.
Is there any way to integrate it to every (new) meeting by default?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to integrate automatic addin in meeting. Alternatively you can create an event as online meeting using Graph API with below request.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events
Prefer: outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"
Content-type: application/json

{
  "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "Does noon work for you?"
  },
  "start": {
      "dateTime": "2017-04-15T12:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
      "dateTime": "2017-04-15T14:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "location":{
      "displayName":"Harry's Bar"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address":"samanthab@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
        "name": "Samantha Booth"
      },
      "type": "required"
    }
  ],
  "allowNewTimeProposals": true,
  "isOnlineMeeting": true,
  "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
}
```

Please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-create-and-enable-an-event-as-an-online-meeting) for more info.

Comment: Hi @heinerludwig please let us know does that help clarify?

Comment: Hi @Mamatha-MSFT, thank you very much! How does the creation of the online meeting solve my problem? I didn't find a way to integrate apps via the graph API.

Comment: @heinerludwig Currently there is no API to integrate add-in. we recommend you to raise a Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a future request.